# Get current user sessionid-Remote desktop/Citrix

Tags: c#, winapi, remote-desktop, multi-user

My application/exe needs to get the session id of the invoker programetically- C#. I have used WTS APIs and check if the session state is active then return session id. This works when there are single users connected to Terminal server. When there are multiple active sessions then the logic fails.

I have referred the URL :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111430/Grabbing-Information-of-a-Terminal-Services-Session

This lists all the sessions. I need to get the session id of the invoker only not all active.

Any help appreciated

Comment: [`ProcessIdToSessionId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-processidtosessionid) ?

Comment: Thanks for reply but my exact requirement is -  I developed windows file watcher service to launch UI (as user give file print from menu) using createuserprocess winapi. It works fine for single user. For multi user this UI get launch in wrong user's session.

So I need launch UI in respective user's session

Comment: and ? you ask how get terminal session id for process. now you say about another - how launch process in concrete session. for this you need use `CreateProcessAsUser` and in `hToken` must be correct session id. or it was already here (depend from how you get this token) or set it direct via `TokenSessionId`